# For loop to concatenate two variables with each element of a list

Tags: python, for-loop

I started learning python this week so maybe it's a dumb question.

I have two variables:

```
folder_path = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop'
b = "\\"
```

and a list containing the file names that are in folder_path:

```
list = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
```

My goal here is to create a new list that each element are the concatenation of **folder_path + b + list[i]**.
For example, `new_list[1]` would be: `r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\file1.txt'`. And so on.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
new_list = list()

for i in list:
    new_list = folder_path + b + list[i]
```

I got the following error: *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

I appreciate it if someone can help :)

Comment: You need to name your list something other than `list`.

Comment: In fact it has another name. I put the name "list" for didactic reasons

Comment: You probably intend `new_list = folder_path + b + i` rather than `new_list = folder_path + b + list[i]`. In your `for` loop, `i` is already an element of the list, not an index to an element in the list. Using the symbol `i` in this context is confusing (since `i` is idiomatically reserved for use as an index). In fact, you seem to have confused yourself.

Comment: What you want is `new_list = [folder_path + b + elem for elem in didactic_list]`.

Comment: What you _really_ want is `os.path.join`, or `pathlib.Path` objects.